# Need to display JWT name under the Grant Types tab in WSo2 application Manager(WSo2 API store)

Tags: jwt, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

[image]

Working on WSo2 Api manager(api store), here i need to display the JWT name under Grant types tab, please see the attached screen shot for more information. Can some body suggest , what i need to  do ,for  displaying  the JWT name under the Grant Types tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can add the name by:

- Open /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/js/applications.js
- Add a new entry under the "config" of the "GrantType" object (first variable) with "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" as the key and "JWT" (Or any desired name) as the value.

eg:

```
var GrantTypes = function (available) {
    this.config = {
        ...
        ...
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer":"JWT"
    }
    ...
    ...
};
```

You can find these steps in [1].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/2433